# Django Cannot resolve keyword 'Word' into field. Choices are:

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have find similar errors on the forum but I don't see any mistakes in my code, and models and views are really not complicated.

```
class Word(models.Model):

    word_text = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user_crea = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    publ_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modi_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class Explanation(models.Model):

    word_foid = models.ForeignKey(Word, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    expl_text = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user_crea = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    publ_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modi_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

So in my opinion Foreign Relationship should be fine. I don't have problems when I'm adding new data by admin panel. I used it in a view:

**views.py**:

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Search(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            dane = form.cleaned_data
            tlumaczenie=Explanation.objects.filter(Word__word_text=dane['Searched_word'])
            print(tlumaczenie)
            return render(request,'explanation.html', {'dane':dane})
```

But I'm still getting error:

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'Word' into field. Choices are: expl_text, id, modi_date, publ_date, user_crea, word_foid, word_foid_id

I don't understand why. It should send query like:

```
select e.* from word w join explanation e on w.word_id = e.word_foid where w.word_text = dane['Searched_word']
```

and retrieve the data.

Any ideas why it's not working properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your foreign key field is called `word_foid`, not `Word`. The query should use that name like this

```
tlumaczenie = Explanation.objects.filter(word_foid__word_text=dane['Searched_word'])
```

Comment: But I don't know word_id. When I'm proceed my view I have word_text only. I think I'm doing just like documentation show it: "Django offers a powerful and intuitive way to “follow” relationships in lookups, taking care of the SQL JOINs for you automatically, behind the scenes. To span a relationship, just use the field name of related fields across models, separated by double underscores, until you get to the field you want.

This example retrieves all Entry objects with a Blog whose name is 'Beatles Blog':

>>> Entry.objects.filter(blog__name='Beatles Blog')"

Comment: `Explanation.objects.filter(word_foid__word_text=dane['Searched_word'])` is what you're looking for